# How to Update Host Keys automatically(with out manual interaction)?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm changing my system but use same IP address to access new system. When trying to access new system, for first Identification changed message was received.

As per this [link](https://rcc.fsu.edu/docs/how-update-host-keys), I have to remove host identification key from .ssh/known_hosts file.

To do this I had write below function in .bashrc & use alias `rmsshk 19` to remove key

```
rmsshkey() {
sed -i $1d /home/pravin/.ssh/known_hosts
}
alias rmsshk=rmsshkey
```

But Now I want to automate it, I know my host identification has changed and I want to update it automatically without my interaction. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "automate" it, but easier way than doing `sed` is to use `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname-or-ip
```

which is much easier and straightforward.

If you don't care about host keys, you can use method described on [Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229124/how-do-i-run-the-ssh-command-to-set-stricthostkeychecking-no/229142#229142).